# Logrotate: Docker + nginx. Can't reload nginx container (logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1])

Tags: docker, nginx, logrotate

I have a **logrotate config:**

```sh
/opt/docker_folders/logs/nginx/*.log {
    dateext
    daily
    rotate 31
    nocreate
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    postrotate
    /usr/bin/docker exec -it nginx-container-name nginx -s reopen > /dev/null 2>/dev/null        
    endscript
    su docker_nginx root
}
```

**folder permissions:**

```sh
drwxrwxr-x. 2 docker_nginx root   4096 Oct 13 10:22 nginx
```

`nginx` is a local host folder mounted to docker container.
`docker_nginx` is a user that has same uid as `nginx` user inside a container (uid: 101).

If I run commands (as root)

```
# /sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/nginx_logrotate_config
# /sbin/logrotate -d -v /etc/logrotate.d/nginx_logrotate_config
# /sbin/logrotate -d -f -v /etc/logrotate.d/nginx_logrotate_config
```

All working like a charm.

**Problem:**
But when log rotating automatically by cron I have get error

```
logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]
```

in `/var/log/messages`

As result logs rotating as usual but nginx don't create new files (access.log, etc).
Looks like postrotate `nginx -s reopen` script failing.

Linux version is CentOS 7.
SELinux disabled.

**Question:**
At least how know what happend when logrotate running from cron?
And what problem may be?

PS I know that I can also use docker restart. But I don't want to do this because of service short time disconnect.

PS2 Also I know that here is `nocreate` parameter in config. That is because I want to create new log files by nginx (to avoid wrong permissions of new files). Anyway, if `nginx -s reopen` really failing, there is a possibility that nginx will not re-read newly created files.

**EDIT1:**
I edited `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` script and get logs.
There is only one line about problem.

```
error: error running non-shared postrotate script for /opt/docker_folders/logs/nginx/access.log of '/opt/docker_folders/logs/nginx/*.log '
```

So I still don't understand what cause this problem... When I run this script manually all running fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. Answering by myself.

`-it` parameters can't be used with cron tasks (and logrotate is also a cron task).
Because cron don't has interactive session (TTY).

I figured it out by running the `/usr/bin/docker exec -it nginx-container-name nginx -s reopen > /dev/null 2>/dev/null` as a cron task. I have got error message `"The input device is not a TTY"`

So my new logrotate config looks like

```
/opt/docker_folders/logs/nginx/*.log {
    dateext
    daily
    rotate 31
    nocreate
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    postrotate
    /usr/bin/docker exec nginx-container-name /bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/nginx -s reopen > /dev/null 2>/dev/null'       
    endscript
    su docker_nginx root
}
```

And it's finally works.

<sup>I have to understand the parameter before using it

I have to understand the parameter before using it

I have to understand the parameter before using it</sup>